# JSONModel NSString Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

in my app i use [Yahoo Api](https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20cricket.scorecard%20where%20match_id=193761&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store://0TxIGQMQbObzvU4Apia0V0&callback=) and get responce i currently use [JSONModel](https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel) in this create a json JSONModel class.

**Past_Match.h** file Like

```
#import <JSONModel/JSONModel.h>
@protocol squadModel @end
@interface squadModel : JSONModel
@property (assign, nonatomic) int i;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *full;
@end


@interface logoModel : JSONModel
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *std;
@end



@protocol teamsModel @end
@interface teamsModel : JSONModel
@property (assign, nonatomic) int i;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *fn;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *sn;
@property (strong, nonatomic) logoModel *logo;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray<squadModel> *squad;
@end

@interface aModel : JSONModel
@property (assign, nonatomic) int i;
@property (assign, nonatomic) int r;
@property (assign, nonatomic) int o;
@property (assign, nonatomic) int w;
@property (assign, nonatomic) int cr;
@end


@interface sModel : JSONModel
@property (strong, nonatomic) aModel *a;
@end

@protocol tModel @end
@interface tModel : JSONModel
@property (assign, nonatomic) int i;
@property (assign, nonatomic) int a;
//@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *c;
//@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *dt;
@property (assign, nonatomic) int fd;
@property (assign, nonatomic) int bd;
//@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *cb;
@property (assign, nonatomic) int b;
@property (assign, nonatomic) int r;
@property (assign, nonatomic) int sr;
@property (assign, nonatomic) int six;
@property (assign, nonatomic) int four;

@end


@interface anewModel : JSONModel
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray<tModel> *t;
@end


@interface dModel : JSONModel
@property (strong, nonatomic) anewModel *a;
@end


@protocol past_ingsModel @end
@interface past_ingsModel : JSONModel
@property (strong, nonatomic) sModel *s;
@property (strong, nonatomic) dModel *d;
@end


@interface ScorecardModel : JSONModel
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *mid;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray<teamsModel> *teams;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray<past_ingsModel> *past_ings;

@end

@interface resultsModel : JSONModel
@property (strong, nonatomic) ScorecardModel *Scorecard;

@end


@interface queryModel : JSONModel
@property (strong, nonatomic) resultsModel *results;

@end


@interface Past_Match : JSONModel
@property (strong, nonatomic) queryModel *query;
@end
```

**Past_Match.m** file Like

```
#import "Past_Match.h"


@implementation squadModel
@end

@implementation logoModel
@end

@implementation teamsModel
@end

@implementation aModel
@end

@implementation sModel
@end

@implementation tModel
@end

@implementation anewModel
@end

@implementation dModel
@end

@implementation past_ingsModel
@end

@implementation ScorecardModel
@end

@implementation resultsModel
@end

@implementation queryModel
@end

@implementation Past_Match
@end
```

in the `tModel` i have issue if i remove `//` and try to get `NSString` of `c`,`dt`,`cd` object than my Past_Match object become Null. that all 3 `NSString` has a same issue i can't get that value. all other value is getting. what i missing something? Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Instead of showing classes that are not part of the question, you should show us the way, you create and check past_Match + the JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error may occurred due to the optional values in your response object try this.... It may works

```
@property (strong, nonatomic)NSString<Optional> *c;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString<Optional> *dt;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString<Optional> *cb;
```

Tip: Please made all properties to Optional

Comment: thanks a lot... i will accept answer right now but it give me waiting for 6 minute....

Comment: in your response object?? where plz explain

Comment: no no in stackoverflow it give me msg you accept answer after 6 minute.